# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, express, sequelize.js

I'm developing a register function in expressjs, but for some reason return me the following message:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

This is my model: `Users.ts`

```
interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  password: string;
  email:string;
  token: string;
  description?: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
  deletedAt?: Date;
}

'use strict';
const {
  Model, Optional
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   class Users extends Model<UserAttributes> {
    public id!: number;
    public first_name!: string;
    public last_name!:string;
    public email!: string;
    public password!: string;
    public token!: string;

  // timestamps!
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
    public readonly deletedAt!: Date;

    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Users.init({
    id: {
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    token: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Users',
    tableName:'users',
  });
  return Users;
};
```

And this is the register controller:

```
async function Register (req:Request, res:Response): Promise<Response> {
  try {
    const {id, first_name, last_name, email, password, token} = req.body;
    await Users.find(email);
    const encrypt: typeof Users = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user: typeof Users  = await Users.create({first_name, last_name, email: email.toLowerCase(), password: encrypt});
    const Token: typeof Users = await jwt.sign({user_id: user.id?.toString(), email:user.email}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    user.token = Token;
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('User couldnt be registered', error);
  }
};
```

Error's message was the following: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

If someone could help me what's the wrong with the code, I'd be really grateful for the help.

Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" is likely caused by the following line of code:

```
const Token: typeof Users = await jwt.sign({user_id: user.id?.toString(), email:user.email}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
```

It looks like the `user` object returned by the `Users.create` method is `undefined`, so the `user.id` property is also undefined and cannot be accessed.

You can try to debug the issue by adding a console.log statement to print the value of user after the create method call.

Another issue is the following line of code

```
await Users.find(email);
```

It should be

```
await Users.findOne({ where: { email } });
```

The find method is not available in sequelize.

Also, in the Users.init, you have defined firstName, lastName but you are using first_name, last_name in the Register function.

You should make sure that you are passing the correct values to the create method, and that the create method is returning a non-undefined object.

Comment: Thanks boddie! I got a question: The code's line would remain like this:      const user: typeof Users  = await Users.create({first_name, last_name, email: email.toLowerCase(), password: encrypt}); return user.id or console.log(user.id). according your proposal? You think that debug the issue?